# Reports from GIT of a given programmer

Tags: git, report

for a documentation of the code for legal issues, I am required to somehow document which exactly files were changed and WHAT EXACTLY was changed in the source code by a given programmer in git repositary. 
Is there any way to make it quite easy and nice?
Maybe there is some tool?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, in the simplest case, you'd just display all commit diffs by that developer:

```
git log -p --author='name of author' --full-history --all
```

To limit `git log`'s output to a time range, specify the `--since`/`--after` and `--until`/`--before` options:

```
git log -p --author='name of author' --since=... --until=... --full-history --all
```

Comment: can I limit the call also by date?

Comment: @MR.GEWA: yes, just look at the [`--since` and `--until`](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-log.html#_commit_limiting) options of `git log`